# is the Probability P(A and A') always 0?

Tags: probability

Would the probability of an event A and its complement occurring always be 0? Is there any case it would not equal 0?

Comment: It is 0 because they are disjoint events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $0$ because $A$ and $A'$ are mutually exclusive events. An event cannot result in two different outcomes at the same time. Mathematically, you're trying to find the probability of empty set (since $A\cap A'$ is empty), which has *zero* probability mass.

Answer (score 5):

$A \cap A^C$ is empty, and so $P(A \cap A^C)  = P(\varnothing) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

that probability is always zero, because A and notA are mutually exclusive events

Comment: I'm new to this website, and I don't know why my answer got downvoted. Is it wrong?

Comment: I think someone misunderstood you, while others try to compensate for it.

Comment: thanks for explaining that and for being friendly to new users

Comment: Maby this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. 
"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."